# Icon Font not working in IE9, but works in other version of IE, and other browsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, font-face, font-awesome

I used font-awesome to generate an icon font for my rails app (not using the gem), and the icon font I created works in Chrome, FF, Safari, and IE10/11 but not IE9.  I created a minimal test case with the following code, and it works in everything but IE9 (this is not rails, just an html file, a css file, and the font files):

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "my-icons";
  src: url("my-icons.eot");
  src: url("my-icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("my-icons.woff") format("woff"),
       url("my-icons.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("my-icons.svg") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.icon-test:before {
  font-family: "my-icons";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  *margin-right: .3em;
}

.icon-test:before { content: "\f113"; }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/font_face.css">
</head>
    <div class="test-container">
        test
        <i class="icon-test"></i>
    </div>
</html>
```

This works just fine in Chrome and FF, but not in IE9. I have messed with formats, MIME types (in the actual rails app), and am not really sure where to go next.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I use custom fonts a lot, I have had face no issues so far. Following is what I would use

```
@font-face {
font-family: "my-icons";
src: url("my-icons.eot?#iefix");
src: url("my-icons.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),
   url("my-icons.woff") format("woff"),
   url("my-icons.ttf") format("truetype"),
   url("my-icons.svg") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: No luck.  That works for you in IE9, specifically?  Because that is the only version of IE where your answer doesn't work for me.